# My R plots are not showing any colors and entire plot become hidden,

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
> library(ggplot2)
> library(gcookbook)
> cabbage_exp
  Cultivar Date Weight        sd  n         se
1      c39  d16   3.18 0.9566144 10 0.30250803
2      c39  d20   2.80 0.2788867 10 0.08819171
3      c39  d21   2.74 0.9834181 10 0.31098410
4      c52  d16   2.26 0.4452215 10 0.14079141
5      c52  d20   3.11 0.7908505 10 0.25008887
6      c52  d21   1.47 0.2110819 10 0.06674995


> b3 = ggplot(cabbage_exp, aes(x = Date, y = Weight, fill = Cultivar))
> b3 + geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "dodge")
> b3 + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Accent")
```

[image: plot]

Idon't know why colors are not showing inside my plots whenever i enter scale_fill_brewer or scale_fill_manual the plot doesn't show

but when i use only this part of code it shows this figure

```
> library(ggplot2)
> library(gcookbook)
> cabbage_exp
  Cultivar Date Weight        sd  n         se
1      c39  d16   3.18 0.9566144 10 0.30250803
2      c39  d20   2.80 0.2788867 10 0.08819171
3      c39  d21   2.74 0.9834181 10 0.31098410
4      c52  d16   2.26 0.4452215 10 0.14079141
5      c52  d20   3.11 0.7908505 10 0.25008887
6      c52  d21   1.47 0.2110819 10 0.06674995
> b3 = ggplot(cabbage_exp, aes(x = Date, y = Weight, fill = Cultivar))
> b3 + geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "dodge")
```

the oucome is

[image: plot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to safe the changes to b3:

```
library(gcookbook)
library(ggplot2)
b3 = ggplot(cabbage_exp, aes(x = Date, y = Weight, fill = Cultivar))
b3 <- b3 + geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "dodge")
b3 <- b3 + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Accent")
b3
```

A better way would be:

```
b3 <- ggplot(cabbage_exp, aes(x = Date, y = Weight, fill = Cultivar)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity",position = "dodge") +
    scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Accent")
b3
```

Comment: **I am so much thankfull to you for your help. i was stuck and unable to move forward. And again thanks for pointing out my mistake**